# Using for loop and if condition in a dictionary containing values in list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dictionary of the form

```
Data = {'USA':[100,250],'Canada':[481,660],'China':[245,700],'Italy':[878,828],'Germany':[643,454]}
```

I can use list comprehension but is there a way to by using "only" for loop in Python, I can output the list of the first elements of each key in the dictionary?

For example, expected output is `[100, 481, 660, 700, 828, 454]`.

And another separate question is how can I output only "the keys" associated with those first elements of those values if greater than 500 by using "for loop", and "if condition", only?

In this case, the output be a list as `Country_list = ['Italy', 'Germany']`.

Comment: You have two questions in one. Please focus it down. (don't kill two stones with one bird)

Comment: A list comprehension is equivalent to calling `append()` on a result list each time through a `for` loop.

Comment: Your output is not the list of the first element of each key. Mostly it's the second, one time both.

Comment: For the second question, loop over `Data.items()` to get both the keys and values. When the value meets the criteria, append the key to `COuntry_list`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a loop, create the list then use one of the dictionary iterators to append when the conditions are right.

```
>>> Data = {'USA':[100,250],'Canada':[481,660],'China':[245,700],'Italy':[878,828],'Germany':[643,454]}
>>> 
>>> result = []
>>> for value in Data.values():
...     result.append(value[0])
... 
>>> result
[100, 481, 245, 878, 643]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> result = []
>>> for key, value in Data.items():
...     if value[0] > 500:
...             result.append(key)
... 
>>> result
['Italy', 'Germany']
```